# How do admins log into iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

The Apple iTunes Connect documentation says this regarding creating an iTunes Connect test user account:

> Only iTunes Connect users with an Admin or Technical role can create
>   test users.

However I am an admin but I can't even log into iTunes connect - when I attempt to I get the message

> Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect.

How can an admin log onto iTunes Connect, or is the Apple documentation incorrect and only the agent can log on?

(P.S. What is an iTunes Connect user with a "Technical role"?)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Admins are generally people who created the first account and then **optionally** creates technical roles. Technical roles are accounts in which you may only do one thing(such as check sales or manage contracts), these accounts are managed by admins.

As to the reason why you cant log in, try resetting your Apple ID...

Comment: Isn't it is the agent who first creates the account and then they optionally create admins. Lets not get the terminology mixed up as its important. Unless the iTunes connect roles are different from the apple developer account roles? What do you mean by resetting the Apple ID?

Comment: ah!, you're part of an organization! I was referencing individual Developer accounts where the developer is the agent. What I mean by resetting Apple ID is to change your password, because once you've registered with apple, you should be able to log in to iTC with your  Apple Id and Password.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "listed as developer"? There are only 6 roles available to users. see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW11

Comment: If you are one of those roles, ask your agent create you a new account. If you are not one of those, Then you may not have an account at all!

Comment: I initially thought iTunes connect roles corresponded to developer account roles however that is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html

> A member with an Admin role in the Apple Developer Program doesn’t automatically have an Admin role in iTunes Connect.

Link above contains instructions.